# VBA code to hide rows n-maximum

Tags: excel

Is there there any code in Excel 2010 VBA that I can use to hide **row n (e.g. row 200)** to the maximum row?

Btw the name of the sheet in particular is *main*.

Comment: Dude come on. We gave you 2 different versions of the solution. Adapt it to your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated comment: To be clear I interpreted this question as hiding from row 200 to the used row with data (if that last used row exceeded 200)*

Something like this

**code**

```
Sub HideEm()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", [a1], xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        If rng1.Row > 200 Then Rows("200:" & rng1.Row).Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**to work on a specific sheet**

```
Sub HideEm()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("main")
Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    If rng1.Row > 200 Then ws.Rows("200:" & rng1.Row).Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So to set it to sheet *main* I would set `Set ws = main`

Answer (score 3):

Normally I would tell you to try and downvote your question but hey I'm lazy this morning so I'll just give you the answer for which you haven't worked for.

`Rows(200, ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).Hidden = true`

Comment: it is lazy - for example it presumes there is data beyond row 200

Comment: He said `to the maximum row` not `to the last row with data`.

Comment: Otherwise we need to know about the spreadsheet a little better to know how to do this.

Comment: So what if there was no data at all in the sheet? (I upvoted your comment above my mistake)