# Hiding rows from 200 on to maximum row in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VBA code to hide rows n-maximum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099486/vba-code-to-hide-rows-n-maximum)

I'm currently using this code to hide rows from number 200 to maximum on Excel VBA but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea on what's wrong?

I already have data in rows 1-200.

```
Sub HideEm()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("main")
Set rng1 = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , , xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    If rng1.Row > 200 Then ws.Rows("200:" & rng1.Row).Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have something in row 201 or greater?  It works for me if I do.  It won't hide if data stops in row 200.

Comment: I haven't got anything but I originally manually hid the rows up until from row 201 to 66178.

Comment: If you just want to hide 200 to the end no matter what, just use this: `ws.Rows("200:" & ws.Rows.Count).Hidden = True`

Comment: @DougGlancy where would I put that code?

Comment: In Sub HideEm I guess.  Whereever it is that you want to hide the rows.

Comment: @DougGlancy so the code would look like this: http://pastebin.com/62yvmxvK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
xlsRange = xlsSheet.Range("A0", "B999") 'select your range, probably need a way to specify from row 200 to maximum, i'm too lazay to do this
xlsRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

these articles will help you creating a dynamic range in VBA

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/isvvba/thread/ef1f8134-f6fc-4f1a-8405-418d4817b0c3

http://www.ozgrid.com/News/excel-dynamic-ranges-vba.htm

Comment: Thanks! How about `xlsSheet.Range("A0", "B999")` - is there a quicker way of specifying row 20 to maximum?